# can't set the right index in a loop

Tags: python, loops, indexing

```
for rout in range(1,6):
    print  'From: '+str(int(s_dict[rout]['Origin']))+','+' to: '+str(int((s_dict[rout]['Destination'])))+','+' Stops: '+(s_dict[rout]['Stops'])+','+' Cost: '+(s_dict[rout]['Cost'])+','+' Time: '+(s_dict[rout]['Time']) 
    print  'All routes:'
    for n in range(len(all_path[rout-1])):
        all_routs=''
        for s in range(len(all_path[rout-1][n])):
            all_routs+=   str(all_path[rout-1][n][s])
            stops=str(len(all_routs)-2)
            cost=0
        for trips in range(len(sec)):
            if sec[trips][X]==(all_path[rout-1][n][0]) or sec[trips][X]==(all_path[rout-1][n][1]):
            cost+=sec[trips][3]    
        print  '->'.join(all_routs)+', Stops: '+stops+', Cost: '+str(cost)
```

the X index is not part of the code because it is what is causing the problem, I can't find a proper way to index it

the purpose of the code is to take "requests" from `s_dict` and match it with `main_dict`'s information of trip. in `s_dict[0]` the customer wants to go from `Origin` '2' to `Destination` '5', `Cost` is 0, that means the price does not matter,same for `Time`,  `Stops` are 99 which also means that it doesn't matter how  many there is.
now I am supposed to find all available paths from '2' to '5' and return how much each costs/consumes time

> s_dict={
>
> 1: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0000.00', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '00.00'},
>
> 2: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0000.00', 'Stops': '11', 'Time': '00.00'},
>
> 3: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1450.11', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '00.00'},
>
> 4: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1550.11', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '22.22'},
>
> 5: {'Origin': '001', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0000.00', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '11.00'}}
>
> main_dict=
>
> {1: {'Origin': '001', 'Destination': '002', 'Cost': '0100.00', 'Time': '04.00'},
>
> 2: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '003', 'Cost': '0500.00', 'Time': '01.50'},
>
> 3: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0700.00', 'Time': '10.00'},
>
> 4: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1500.00', 'Time': '05.75'},
>
> 5: {'Origin': '003', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0200.00', 'Time': '11.40'},
>
> 6: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0750.00', 'Time': '10.50'},
>
> 7: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0550.00', 'Time': '06.75'}}

from the `main_dict` I took the info out since it is easier for me to work with it this way and made `sec`

> sec=[
>
> [1, 2, 4.0, 100.0],
>
> [2, 3, 1.5, 500.0],
>
> [2, 4, 10.0, 700.0],
>
> [2, 5, 5.75, 1500.0],
>
> [3, 4, 11.4, 200.0],
>
> [4, 5, 10.5, 750.0],
>
> [4, 6, 6.75, 550.0]]
>
> all_path=[
>
> [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]],
>
> [[4, 5]],
>
> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5]]]

the `all_path` comes from the `s_dict`
it take 2 specific values in three first cases it is 2->5 which means I want to go from origin 2 to destination 5, I am supposed to show every available rout, that means 2->3->4->5, 2->4->5, 2->5
and that's the path, now I am trying to get the cost of every trip.
in other words if we take 2->4->5 then in the s_dict it will take 2 as origin and 3 as destination, outs the value of the cost in the `cost` variable then takes 3 as origin and 4 as destination and sums the cost to value to the `cost` variable.
my problem is here with the index `if sec[trips][0]==(all_path[tin-1][n][X]) or sec[trips][1]==(all_path[tin-1][n][X]):` the problem is mostly how to index X "X is not part of the code"
I have tried so many methods to solve it but it won't work, best I got was it changing the destination and keeping the same origin all the time, so cost of 2->3 + 2->4 + 2->5 instead of 2->3 + 3->4 + 4->5

Comment: I can't seem to work out what we need `sec` data for

Comment: Actually, I've read 3 times and each time I get more confused. At least in my case, it would be much easier if you break that block of text down and make it more specific. For example, I guessed that `sec` had something like `[origin, destination, something, something]` but then that would go up to `6`, yet you only have up to `5` named locations. Then we have `s_dict` which only ever has `5` as a destination and 99 "stops". Nothing seems to relate to the other and I can't get it from the code because that's faulty.

Comment: I agree with @roganjosh, the code is so difficult to read. Also, what version of python are you using? In general, please state a problem. We don't know what `tin` is, and in general everything is not easy to comprehend.

Comment: it is a very long code, tin is just an index mate

Comment: That's not a particularly useful response. We can see that `tin` is an index but we actually have to visualise what you're trying to do. `tin` has no meaning to us, so when you have heavily nested loops and no basis to understand what's going on, it just gets _more_ confusing. Your code has gone down a rabbit hole to solve this problem, it needs refactoring and that can **only** be done if you give a clear problem statement and clear indication of what your data structures mean.

Comment: To be clear, I understand the actual outcome reasonably clearly. But I have no hope of getting to the outcome as it is.

Comment: if there's a way to do it in another way? because currently I am clueless

Comment: Yes. You could respond appropriately to both of my observations and that of @Narusan. In it's current state this is _totally unanswerable_ as a question. Please edit it.

Comment: I have written an answer for you to show you ways of improving your question.

Comment: I hope the edit helps now

Comment: To be honest, it still is very difficult to comprehend. You could help us a lot by stating what you are trying to do, and how you do it. This way, we have to understand how your code could work and it is very difficult to do.

Comment: It does, a lot. Let me see if I can come up with a solution without you needing to post the whole data structures.

Comment: Actually no, I'm still confused! Ok, so `cost` in `s_dict` only has meaning if it's `!= 0`? Then it's an extra penalty?

Comment: if time/cost is 0 that means the costumer doesn't care about their value, it could be anything same for stops if it is 99 then it doesn't matter how many there is

Comment: Ok, I think I understand enough of the general approach to get a general answer to illustrate the approach rather than solve this specific issue because we'll be here all night. I'm assuming that there's a lot of superfluous info in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lengthy to and fro in the comments, I don't think this can be answered for your *specific* problem. I am running on the assumption that you already solved the issue of `costs=99` by the time you get to `all_path`. In that case, I think you should refactor your code into something like the following, to get rid of the indexing hell you've found yourself in. It's by no means perfectly refined, but hopefully easier to follow.

```
import random
import itertools 

###### Generate some fake data for our dict ######

# First get all of our location pairings as tuples
loc_pairs = list(itertools.product(range(1, 6), range(1, 6)))

# Build cost dictionary. Tuple key is (from-location, to-location)
cost_dict = {}
for loc_pair in loc_pairs:
    cost_dict[loc_pair] = {'cost': random.randint(0, 50), 
                           'time': random.randint(0, 50)}

##### Now your data for paths ######
all_path=[[[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]], [[4, 5]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
            [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5]]]

### Build the printout
for start_location in all_path:
    for route in start_location:
        locations_visited = ' -> '.join(str(item) for item in route)
        costs = 0
        times = 0
        try:
            for x in range(len(route)-1):
                costs += cost_dict[(route[x], route[x+1])]['cost']
                times += cost_dict[(route[x], route[x+1])]['time']
            print("The route: {}".format(locations_visited))
            print("costs:     {}".format(costs))
            print("took:      {}".format(times))
        except:
            pass
```

Assuming your `main_dict` is accurate in its data structure, you could build a real cost dictionary with:

```
real_costs = {1: {'Origin': '001', 'Destination': '002', 'Cost': '0100.00', 'Time': '04.00'},
2: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '003', 'Cost': '0500.00', 'Time': '01.50'},
3: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0700.00', 'Time': '10.00'},
4: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1500.00', 'Time': '05.75'},
5: {'Origin': '003', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0200.00', 'Time': '11.40'},
6: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0750.00', 'Time': '10.50'},
7: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '006', 'Cost': '0550.00', 'Time': '06.75'}}

real_cost_dict = {}

for key, value in real_costs.items():
    pairing = (value.get('Origin'), value.get('Destination'))
    real_cost_dict[pairing] = {'cost': value.get('Cost'), 
                               'time': value.get('Time')}
```

Comment: I kinda need the indexing because there's some printing order, but you gave me an idea, although currently I can't think of an exact way to create  a cost_dict, but if it work then I think that will solve it

Comment: @Enigma is that an accurate representation of `main_dict` in your question? In other words, there's an index that corresponds to another dictionary like `{'Origin': '003', 'Destination': '004', 'Cost': '0200.00', 'Time': '11.40'},`? In which case, we could build a cost dictionary easy enough from that.

Comment: in the code I open a given file, take values from it and apply it to the main_dict, this is what my current main_dict looks like, the values can change from file to file but it will have the same keys

Comment: I am not really sure but it is not returning "printing" anything

Comment: @Enigma what isn't? The first block or the second? My first block for sure runs in Python 2 and I don't use Python 3 so I might have missed something.

Comment: I am using python 2, yes the first runs great but the second isn't catching well.. maybe I am putting things together the wrong way, I will gave it a better look

Comment: @Enigma confirmed on my end that the `real_cost_dict` will give results if you run my code snippet. The error must be in how you're applying it in your problem setup.

Comment: @Enigma great to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

What basically is desired here is a function of some sort, if I have understood the code correctly.

Basically:

```
def path_finding_algorithm('[INPUT]'):
    //loads of processing here
    //
    // '[PROCESS]'
    //
    return '[OUTPUT]'
```

You have only provided us with the `['OUTPUT']` and a shortened version of the `['PROCESS']`. But we have to know what the `['INPUT']` is and what the `['PROCESS']` is trying to do.
Otherwise, there is insufficient information to answer your question.

A good place to start is stating a situation:

> I am designing a path finding-algorithm for something like a navigation app. I do this using a grid map with costs as distance
>   between vertices. This is my cost function:
>
> //CODE//
>
> Is there a way to optimise it?